# gitolite - smart-http - gives uninitialised value for rc("UMASK")

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, gitolite

I'm getting the following error in my `/var/log/apache2/error.log` when I try to do a git clone to my server running gitolite with smart-http enabled

```
[Wed Jul 25 21:53:36 2012] [error] [client 124.149.104.106] FATAL: warn\tUse of 
uninitialized value $rc{"UMASK"} in umask at /opt/git/gitolite-source/src/
gitolite-shell line 95, <DATA> line 1.<<newline>>
```

I do have the `UMASK` value set to `0027` in `/home/git/.gitolite.rc`

Any thoughts why the value isn't setting when called from an su_exec from a file in `sites-available`?

I'm running apache as www-data - and have set up permissions on the various scripts as per the instructions [here](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/ssh-and-http.html) - ie:

```
install -d -m 0755 -o git -g git /var/www/bin
install -d -m 0755 -o www -g www /var/www/git
```

and then:

create a shell script inside `/var/www/bin` named `gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh`, with mode `0700` and owned by user and group `git`.

Comment: Does your apache runs as git? Otherwise, the $HOME mentioned in https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L123 might not be the right one.

Comment: Hi VonC - your presentation on git in the enterprise was awesome. (In addition to your other clearcase answers).  I'll edit the answer now.

Comment: Thank you. It is not yet an official one, but you can see it again at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2swiB8QOHk

Comment: Are you saying that the $HOME is still an issue?

Comment: @Regarding  `GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME` seems correctly set. But I had issue with that variable before. setting `HOME` in the http session of in the wrapper would still be interesting though, to test that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got it - basically I reinstalled starting from scratch:

1. [Install gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/install.html) (installing the source to the `/home/git` directory and running the setup as the `git` user using `su - git`)
2. Read [the warning here](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite-doc/blob/master/http.mkd)
3. Run [the steps in this document](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/t/smart-http.root-setup) (ie not run the file - just line by line)
4. Don't run [the exports here](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/http.html) as we'll run gitolite as the git user
5. Install gitweb using apt-get - configure it to point to the repositories at `/home/git/repositories`
6. Put the following into the apache site configuration here `/etc/apache2/sites-available/git.servername.com`

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAdmin mail@servername.com
       ServerAlias git
       ServerName git.servername.com

       DocumentRoot /var/www/git

       <Directory /var/www/git>
         Options +Indexes
         AllowOverride none
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
       </Directory>

       SuexecUserGroup git git
       ScriptAlias /git/ /var/www/bin/gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh/
       ScriptAlias /gitmob/ /var/www/bin/gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh/

       <Location /git>
         AuthType Basic
         AuthName "Git Access"
         Require valid-user
         AuthUserFile /home/git/gitolite-http-authuserfile
       </Location>
       Loglevel warn
       ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
       CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
7. Use the [styles for gitweb from here](http://computercamp.cdwilson.us/git-gitolite-git-daemon-gitweb-setup-on-ubunt).
8. Now I can access my site via ssh using
   `git clone ssh://git@git.servername.com:gitolite-admin.git`
   http://admin@git.servername.com/git/testing.git

   and view it at 
   http://servername.com/gitweb