# Gitolite error .gitolite.rc' seems to be for older gitolite; please see doc/g2migr.mkd

Tags: git, gitolite

I have installed gitolite using `rpm` in centos6 ie `gitolite-2.3.1-1.el6.noarch.rpm` and after `rpm` installation I have run the `gl-setup`.
I am trying to access repo over http. When I try to clone  git clone `http://server.name/git/gitoliteadmin.git` it gives error:

```
FATAL: '/var/opt/jet/gitolite/.gitolite.rc' seems to be for older gitolite; please see doc/g2migr.mkd
(online at http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2migr.html)

Premature end of script headers: gitolite-shell
```

Below is my `htpd.conf` configuration

```
<VirtualHost 10.111.123.17:80>
ServerName server.name
LogLevel Debug
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME /var/opt/gitolite
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/opt/gitolite/repositories
SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
ScriptAlias /git/ /opt/git_install/gitolite-master/src/gitolite-shell/
SetEnv /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend

<Location /git>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Git CLone"
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
  Require valid-user
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Location>

<LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$">
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from All
        AuthName "GIT Repo"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthzLDAPAuthoritative On
        Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Not sure what is wrong. Also while `rpm` installation the `gitolite-shell` was not part of `rpm` package.
So I downloaded the zip file from sitaramc and added the gitolite-shell path.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You have installed through rpm an old version of gitolite: a V2 instead of the more mature V3 (which includes [`gitolite-shell`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/gitolite-shell)).

I would recommend installing gitolite by cloning the GitHub repo

```
git clone git://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite
```

And following the [installation documentation](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/install.html#req) for Gitolite V3.
And then follow git [gitolite setup](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/setup.html):

```
gitolite setup -pk alice.pub
```

(that is the new form of what used to be `gl-setup` in gitolite V2)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But due to security reasons cloning from other sites are restricted.

Comment: @user2164525 It doesn't matter: you don't have to clone. You can download the archive and unzip it: https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/archive/v3.5.2.tar.gz

Comment: @user2164525 if this is blocked as well, update your rpm source with http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=gitolite, in order to install a gitolite 3.5.x instead of a 2.x

Comment: I have installed via rpm gitolite3-3.5.2-1.el6.noarch.rpm. When i try to run gl-setup it says -sh: gl-setup: command not found. Also when i tried to find the gl-set script i didnt find in /usr/bin.

Comment: @user2164525 that is perfectly normal: `gl-setup` is from gitolite V2. I have mention in my answer the proper link for the installation documentation: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/install.html#req. You will see a command like `gitolite/install`, *not* `gl-setup`.

Comment: I am looking for equivalent command for gl-setup  ~/.ssh/gitolite.pub to add my ssh key

Comment: @user2164525 assuming that you have followed the installation process for gitolite V3, then the next step is described in "setup": http://gitolite.com/gitolite/setup.html. `gitolite setup -pk alice.pub`

Comment: Getting the below error in apache logs  FATAL: warn\tUse of uninitialized value $rc{"UMASK"} in umask at /usr/share/gitolite3/gitolite-shell line 95, <DATA> line 1.<<newline>>

Comment: @user2164525 then close/accept this answer first: this is way beyond the original question. You can ask another question with the new context, but first, try and follow http://stackoverflow.com/q/11649208/6309