# Can't push gitolite-admin by braking gitolite.conf

Tags: git, bash, gitolite, git-bash

Usually i find my answers by trying different solutions i find on stackoverflow but really, nothing seems to work today.

I installed gitolite and it took me like two days before i got my main user to clone and push (proved to be the problem that i did not add the new user 'git' to the sshd-config under AllowUsers). But still, i got it working like a charm... before this afternoon, because that was when i broke it.

so what i did in my gitolite.conf was making a nice group:

```
    @admin_group = my-desktop-name my-laptop-name my-server-user-name
    repo gitolite-admin
    RW+ = admin_group
```

and this last line was where the @ sign was forgotten. it should have been:

```
    RW+ = @admin_group
```

Not knowing id did:

```
    git add *
    git push
```

Here i am. Not able to push again after committing the code were i added the @ sign.

I did came to this page: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/emergencies.html
and followed instructions..

```
   git clone     $HOME/repositories/gitolite-admin.git temp
   cd temp
```

Then i changed the config file the way i think it should be. But than ended up with:

```
    ~/temp$ gitolite push
    -su: gitolite: command not found
```

Also tried to push it with 'git push' but that also did not work.
I think i'm very close with http://gitolite.com/gitolite/emergencies.html
Can anyone give me that last push?

As followup to what i actually did to make it all work (starting as main_user):

```
    cd ~
    cp .ssh/id_rsa.pub main_user.pub
    sudo su - git
    rm -rf *
    rm -rf .*
    mkdir -p ~/bin
    git clone git://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite
    gitolite/install -ln /home/git/bin
    bin/gitolite setup -pk /home/main_user/main_user.pub
    exit
    git clone git@my_domain:gitolite-admin
```

Now i only have to do the settings again and i'm good to go. Tnx for the help VonC!

Comment: Great! you can post your edit as an answer and select it.

Answer (score 1):

When you [install gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/install.html), you are suppose to install it in a path included in your `$PATH` environment variable, like:

```
gitolite/install -to $HOME/bin
```

That would allow gitolite to work in your case.

Comment: Valid argument but i did not clone the repository from github. I used: sudo apt-get install gitolite. and then gl-setup.
Where to go from this situation?

Comment: gl-setup? Are you using an old gitolite v2? Scrap that, and clone the github repo.

Comment: (as I mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/19348518/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/18503812/6309)